# Probability outcomes

Tags: probability

There are 33 cards total, 8 are blue the rest are red. 2 people are drawing from the deck at the same time what is the probability of one person drawing a red card? Also what is the probability if only 1 person is drawing instead of 2?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** there are 3 outcomes:

- BR
- BB
- RR

For instance, there are $8\times 25$ possibilities for the first one. Compute all the different possibilities, and make the ratio over the total to get the answers.